# xAxis values groups as slices + labels in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How could one achieve the xAxis series 'slices' & outer labels grouping/sub-series as seen in the example below?

[image]

chart source: http://data.worldjusticeproject.org/#/groups/BRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is not something that comes off-the-shelf with Highcharts.  The example you provided appears to involve creating some of their own custom visuals. It all takes place in the following file:

http://data.worldjusticeproject.org/scripts/0d579abd.main.js

By [beautifying](http://jsbeautifier.org/) this JavaScript, you can see that the outer labels are added *declaratively*. For example:

```
function() {
        "use strict";
        Roli.Labels = ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "4.1", "4.2", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6", "4.7", "4.8", "5.1", "5.2", "5.3", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", "6.4", "6.5", "7.1", "7.2", "7.3", "7.4", "7.5", "7.6", "7.7", "8.1", "8.2", "8.3", "8.4", "8.5", "8.6", "8.7"], Roli.Descriptions = {
            "1.0": "Constraints on Government Powers",
            1.1: "Limits by legislature",
            1.2: "Limits by judiciary",
            1.3: "Independent auditing",
            1.4: "Sanctions for official misconduct",
            1.5: "Non-governmental checks",
            1.6: "Lawful transition of power",
            "2.0": "Absence of Corruption",
    ...
    ...
}
```

They then go on to define a function `drawRadar` which makes use of these labels.  This takes place in extending a view in Backbone: http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend